# Send template push notification message using azure notification hub

Tags: push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Hi i want to send Template notification using azure notification hub. I want to send json object (key value pair) in notification and from app site they will process it and will display. I tried using bellow code but i am not getting notification !

```
    var notificationMessage = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "PushType", "0" }, { "Id","6" }, { "Type", "0"}, { "SubType", "0" }, { "Title", "test" } };

 await instance.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(notificationMessage, user.UserID.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what is happening without knowing details about code and configuration.

But I would recommend going through the following to troubleshoot:

- [Azure Notification Hubs - Diagnosis guidelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer/)
- [Using Azure Notification Hubs Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn530748.aspx)

Let me know if you cannot find a solution using links above.